# Is there a best way in my code to check for the values in my list?

Tags: python

I have a list of list, let's say : `list = [[34,50,0],[21,38,0],[48,69,0],[23,90,0],[12,21,0]]`

What's the best way to do the following:

```
for i in range(112):  
    for j in range(112):
        for k in list:  

            if k[0]=i and k[1]=j:  
                # do something  

            else: 
                # do something else
```

Comment: Why 112? Shouldn't it be [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **very** vague what you are asking, but something like the following **list comprehension** will add `True` to a list every time `k[0]=i and k[1]=j`, otherwise `False`.

```
values = [True if k[0] == i and k[1] == j else False for j in range(112) for i in range(112) for k in list]
```

Just in case you are wondering, there are `several` problems with your code that you want to fix, even though it may be pseudo-code:

1. Your indenting is off
2. Your name `list` shadows the built-in
3. You call `if k[0]=i and k[1]=j:` which uses only one `=`. It should be `if k[0] == i and k[1] == j:`